# convert a date in this format '031012' into a date that I can add days to

Tags: php, date

I have a date in this format `030512` (ddmmyy).
But I'm having trouble with converting this to a date usable format I can add days to.

Basically.. I extracted the date above from a text file, Now I need to be able to add a number of days to it. But I am having trouble parsing the date in this format.

Is there another way of doing this rather then something like this:

```
// I have a date in this format
$date = '030512'; // 03 May 2012

$day = substr($date,0,2);
$month = substr($date, 2,2);
$year = substr($date, 4,2);
$date_after = $day . "-" . $month . "-".$year;

// Now i need to add x days to this
$total_no_nights = 010; // must be this format
$days_to_add = ltrim($total_no_nights,"0"); // 10, remove leading zero

// how do i add 10 days to this date.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the date will always be in the future (or at least after 1st Jan 2000), you're not far wrong:

```
// I have a date in this format
$date = '030512'; // 03 May 2012

$day = substr($date,0,2);
$month = substr($date, 2,2);
$year = substr($date, 4,2);
// dd-mm-yy is not a universal format but we can use mktime which also gives us a timestamp to use for manipulation
$date_after = mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year );

// Now i need to add x days to this
$total_no_nights = "010"; // must be this format
$days_to_add = intval( $total_no_nights ); // No need to use ltrim

// Here's the "magic". Again it returns a timestamp
$new_date = strtotime( "+$days_to_add days", $date_after );
```

Using the DateTime object would be easier but you say you're not on PHP5.3.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this (php >= 5.3):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', '030512');
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

For php < 5.3 :

```
$dateArray = str_split('030512', 2);
$dateArray[2] += 2000;
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime('+1 day', strtotime(implode('-', array_reverse($dateArray)))));
```

Comment: @JustAnil Fixed for php < 5.3 :)

Comment: @JustAnil Neither of these solutions work. The given date is the 3rd May. These both return 06/03/2012 which is either 3rd June (US format) or 6th March (European format). See my post for a more robust answer.

Answer (score 3):

try this using the month/day/year you already have:

```
$date = "$month/$day/$year";
$change = '+10 day';
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($change, strtotime($date)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do date manipulation with strings becase, well, they are not dates. In PHP, you can use Unix timestamps (which are actually integers...) or DateTime objects. In you case:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('-10 days', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
echo date('r', $timestamp);
```

... or:

```
$object = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day");
$object->modify('-10 days');
echo $object->format('r');
```

Also, please note that `010` is an octal number that corresponds to `8` in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

using the convert function in sql the date can be obtained in appropriate format.

anter that operations can be performed in php to manipulate the date. i hope that answers your query.

Comment: He said he extracted the date form a text file, no reference to sql.

Comment: noted. i assumed it was being extracted as text data from sql.